# Files deleted with git filter-branch reappear after push and pull back

Tags: git, gitlab, git-filter-branch

I have some sensitive info in the repository. Trying to sanitize it and then push to GitLab. However, once pulled from GitLab, the sanitized info reappears. Where is my mistake?

```
git log -Smypassword

<returns some commits showing that mypassword is indeed in the repo>

# clean the repo from mypassword
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter "find . -name '*.js' -exec sed -i -e 's/mypassword/nomorepassword/g' {} \;"^C

git log -Smypassword
<nothing found, indicating that git filter-branch worked>

git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:user/project.git

# I have two unmerged branches
git push -u origin master
git push -u origin accounts

cd ../fresh

git clone  git@gitlab.com:user/project.git

git log -Smypassword

<returns some commits again>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does it output when you do git push? Since you're rewriting the branch history you usually have to force push. And I hope you are aware of the consequences of force pushing.

Comment: This is my first push to the brand new remote repo, so no force push

Comment: I merged the other branch into master and redid it. Works now. Can't tell whether it was an error on my part, or two branches have something to do with it.

Comment: @ТаняТ. it's worth writing an answer )

Comment: Not much of an answer, but I did :)

Comment: @ТаняТ. could it be that `filter-branch ` only touched `master` and not the other branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I merged the other branch into master and redid it. Works now. Can't tell whether it was an error on my part, or two branches have something to do with it.